# Laravel - Overwrite Blade Template with another

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, template-engine, laravel-blade

I'm using Laravel 4.1.30

I was wondering if it's possible to to overwrite a template with a different template:

**Like this I would have:**

```
Show.blade.php
```

**The i would make in the same directory it's located:**

```
 _Show.blade.php
```

That second file would have the same content as the original, but able to be modified, that way i don't have to change the original.

Is this possible in laravel, or would that be impossible?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could do that by extending the view class and overloading the view locating method to first try `_*` files, but I really don't see why you would need that. I suspect an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @AndréDaniel The sort of system Terrabyte describes is pretty common in the the CMS world and some other MVC frameworks. It's useful for giving front-end only developers the agency to change templates without expect them to edit core application code.

Comment: do you know how i would be able to implement this?

Comment: I think you should consider writing a package which allows you to [override views without changing the core](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/packages#package-views)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Laravel 4.2.x

Well i couldn't find a way to do the hierarchy for files but there is a method for folders. Found the answer a while back.

So we would first go to:

```
app/start/global.php <- global classloader
```

and add:

```
View::addLocation(public_path('app/views'));
```

Then go to:

```
app/config/view.php
```

and change:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| View Storage Paths
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Most templating systems load templates from disk. Here you may specify
| an array of paths that should be checked for your views. Of course
| the usual Laravel view path has already been registered for you.
|
*/

'paths' => array(__DIR__.'/../views'),
```

to:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| View Storage Paths
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Most templating systems load templates from disk. Here you may specify
| an array of paths that should be checked for your views. Of course
| the usual Laravel view path has already been registered for you.
|
*/

'paths' => array(__DIR__.'/../views-custom'),
```

You can change 'views-custom' to whatever you like but all changes made within that folder will be preferred over the 'views' folder. So its more of a folder hierarchy option.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can write a function. to give you an idea, this code is not entirely php:

```
$template = 'show.view.php';

if(file_exists('_' . $template)){
    return '_' . $template;
}else{
    $template;
}
```